# How to Update & Delete Roles in Sentinel Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have done with user role create. below is its code.

```
$role = Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->createModel()->create([
    'name' => request('name'),
    'slug' => request('slug')           
]);
```

But I am not sure if below update & delete code will work.

> Delete Code

```
$role = Sentinel::findRoleById($this->data['id']));
```

> Edit Code ( I know its wrong, because it making no sense :) )

```
$role = Sentinel::findRoleById(request('role_id'));
$role = Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->createModel()->update([
    'name' => request('name'),
    'slug' => request('slug')
]);
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You want to delete role as whole or role which is assigned to any user ?

Comment: I want to delete role as whole not at role which assigned to any user or something.

Comment: I believe what you can find out what you are looking for here https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0. The update and delete is stated there. It's far down but it's there

Comment: @FatimahSanni I checked it. There is update/delete role for user is there but not anything related to delete whole role or update or list all roles.

For now I have created Role Model to do above stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following code. That should normally work.

```
$role = Sentinel::findRoleById($id);
$role->delete();
```